# DataTable does not update content

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm using the jQuery DataTable plugin but I have an issue, in my page I can edit the information from an specific row I do this with AJAX and JavaScript, my function is something like this:

```
$.ajax ... code 
success function... code and finally
DrawMyTable();
```

DrawMyTable is another AJAX, the code is something like this:

```
$.ajax ... code (Select * from and that stuff)
   var html = "";
   var html += "<tr>";
   var html += "<td>";
   var html += ... Then I do this for all the result from the Select Query;
   var html += "</td>";
   var html += "</tr>"; and finally
   $('#MyTable').html(html); 
   $('#MyTable').DataTable().destroy(); //Looking here for answer I find that this could be a solution because before facing this issue I had the "cannot reinitialise datatable" error.
   $('#MyTable').DataTable();
```

**EDIT #2**

```
$('#MyTable').DataTable().destroy(); 
This have an error, the correct function is $('#MyTable').dataTable().destroy();
However with this I get the same issue, the table now is uptated but shows all the records.
```

**EDIT:**

What I tried was using this (**With this the table is updated but shows all my records instead of only 10, 25 or whatever the user select**):

```
$("#MyTable").DataTable().fnDestroy();
$("#MyTable").DataTable();
```

This:

```
$('#MyTable').DataTable({
            bRetrieve: true
Or
$('#MyTable').DataTable({
            destroy: true
```

But I get the same result, my table is loaded as expect, but when I edit something (editing something should reload the table) appears my success button but my table doesn't change until I reload the page, and also my table pagination is re initiated (for example at the beginning I show 10 records per page, but when I call my edit function the table shows all the records) what I'm doing wrong? How can solve this problem?

PD. I can't use AJAX option for DataTable because I need to insert other information that I don't get from the ajax call.

**EDIT #3**

Here is [My full JavaSript Code](https://anotepad.com/notes/x5d6ed)

PD2. My webservice are simple, just some sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a DataTable displayed...
Then you want to add an additional row to it, using ajax.

The way I would do it is to `push` the new values obtained via ajax to the data used by DataTable to `draw`.

The data needs to be an array containing an array for each rows... Like this:

```
var myTable;
var data;
$(document).ready(function() {
    data = [ ["Text for cell#1 - row 1","Text for cell#2 - row 1","Text for cell#3 - row 1"]
             ["Text for cell#1 - row 2","Text for cell#2 - row 2","Text for cell#3 - row 2"]
             ["Text for cell#1 - row 3","Text for cell#2 - row 3","Text for cell#3 - row 3"]
           ];

    myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        data:data
    });

    // Draw the table
    myTable.draw();
} );
```

So afterward...  In the ajax success callback, I would create an array like this from the results:
(You may have to use a loop to format it correctly)

```
var newData = ["Text for cell#1 - row 4","Text for cell#2 - row 4","Text for cell#3 - row 4"]
```

Then `push` it to `data` array and re-draw the table.

```
data.push(newData);
myTable.draw();
```

Comment: I'm trying to solve my problem and seems to work with the options that I mentioned I tried but with that options now when I update something the table shows all the records instead of the selected number, what can be the problem? Should I upload a text file with my entire functions?

Comment: The thing is that you try to do the work Datatable does... By forming the table's inner html (tr an td) line by line. The way I would do it is to give the data formed in an array and let DataTable do its work.

Comment: This will also preserve the column ordering and the search functions. If you "replace" the rows... These functions will fail because it is based on the data.

Comment: I attach a link to my full javascript functions, for the moment I'm going to try to do what you said

Comment: I just had a quick look to your full code. So you have some of the DataTable cells that are editable and what you really want to do is to save the edits... Am I right?

Comment: You're right, with the code that I post in that URL I'm able to edit a cell and the table is update, the default records per page is 10 but when my table is reload after I edit something table shows all records instead of 10

Comment: That is because you "forced" the html inside. The pagination is also based on the data array I'm talking.

Comment: So in other words there is no other option that use a data array?

Comment: Exact, that is what I recommend.